# Puppet like syntax for python

Tags: python, puppet

Anyone know of any good ways to do puppet like pp files for python. Almost like config files that can inherit other configs files and also have limited logic in them like if statements and variables?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific? What exactly do you mean by "for python"? Do you mean you want your program to read configuration files similar to puppet?

Comment: looking to add into my python app puppet like config files that are more like programming language.

Comment: cfgparse supports python in config files: http://cfgparse.sourceforge.net/cfgparse-python.html although looks like it hasn't been updated recently so not sure on its status

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Kokki](http://samuelks.com/kokki/) is an interesting project which attempts to be Chef / Puppet but for Python.  It looks a little immature to use in production, but if you're looking for a Python-based configuration management system and don't want to use something more well established (and heavy-handed) like Bcfg2, I'd go with Kokki.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Python, with in-house rules limiting what can appear in a config file.

The advantages are that no one has to learn another language, it's really, really cheap to implement, and you don't have to worry about maintenance of the config parser. The disadvantages are that it's not a custom-designed language for your particular use-case, and that if you're not strict in limiting what syntax may be used you'll end up with mushrooming complexity in your config files.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software) is a pretty good list of open source configuration management tools. Good Python implementations include Synctool, Salt, Pacha, and Bcfg2.